# .nil? function not working in Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

```
def names
  if first_name.nil? && last_name.nil?
    errors.add(:first_name, "First Name and Last Name both can't be empty!")
  end
end
```

and even if I write so, it should allow either first or last name to be nil but not both. It doesn't work as expected

Comment: I suggest you add debugging right before your if and check the values. I can positively guarantee you that you have not found a bug in ``.nil?``.

Comment: If no value is entered in the input field, the values of first_name and last_name will be ''. So it's string not nil. Try using blank? instead of nil?.

Comment: Probably you might have to check for `first_name.empty? && last_name.empty?` as well. As a string possibly empty string might also struct the request.

Comment: Two possibilities: 1) Rails breaks `nil?` and nobody cares 2) your value is not `nil` ;-)

Comment: @Shreya : Show an example where it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `blank?` or `present?` methods instead of `nil?`, they both check for empty strings and `nil`'s